# Sheet display in function of date and time on open and save (2)

Tags: vba, excel, automation

Since I had to almost start all of the code again with first refactor and an eye opening advice on a random Overflow question, here it is again:

This is a code that selects the right sheet according to the day of the week(date) and time(Now).

The code finds the day of the week (in French), determines if we are in night or day shift depending on time limits also depending of the days: it then concatenates the 2 ex: "Thursday" + "night" and finds the sheets name accordingly.

If it does not find a match (Friday night or weekend) it selects Friday sheet

[image: feuille]

The code is runned by workbook_open and beforeSave, so it need to be optimized as much as possible.

Here the whole code:

```
    Public Sub SelectionDeQuartAuto()
        Dim wsactivate As Boolean    ' Boolean turns true if ws is activated
        Dim joursemaine As String    ' Day of the week
        joursemaine = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Date, "[$-40c]DDDD")
        Dim shift As String          
        shift = Shiftselect(IsDayShift(Now)) ' Returns "Day" or "Night" shifts
    
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' Loops trough all .visible ws to find a match w day+shift
            If ws.Visible Then
                If InStr(1, ws.Name, joursemaine & " " & shift, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 'If ws.name contain day of the week + day or night shift 
                    ws.Activate
                    wsactivate = True 
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If wsactivate = False Then           ' If no match 
            Sheets("Vendredi jour").Activate ' Activate friday
        End If
    End Sub
    
    Public Function Shiftselect(Isday As Boolean) As String
    ' Returns "Day" or "Night" string depending on IsDay boolean
        If Isday Then
            Shiftselect = "jour"
        Else
            Shiftselect = "soir"
        End If
    End Function
    
    Public Function IsDayShift(ByVal DateTime As Date) As Boolean
    ' Return a true boolean if we are outside night shift boundaries, return false elseways
        If weekday(DateTime, vbSunday) = vbThursday Then ' If we are thursday night shift boundaries are different
            IsDayShift = TimeValue(DateTime) > TimeValue("03:00:00") And TimeValue(DateTime) < TimeValue("15:15:00") ' If Time is outside night shift limit assume its day shift
        Else ' Monday to wednesday + friday (no night shift on friday) use normal boundaries
            IsDayShift = TimeValue(DateTime) > TimeValue("03:00:00") And TimeValue(DateTime) < TimeValue("16:15:00")
        End If
End Function
```